# YouTube API Thumbnail set endpoint throws 403 forbidden

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a NodeJS automation script to configure YouTube Live streams. The script worked fine till December 9th, 2020. Since then we are getting 403 error on the Thumbnail set endpoint. Tried updating the NodeJS Google Data API package and regenerating OAuth token with the suggested scopes but nothing helps. Documentation doesn't suggest any change/deprecation either.

```
try {
  var thumbnailResponse = await service.thumbnails.set({
    auth: auth,
    videoId: liveVideoId,
    media: {
      body: fs.createReadStream(languageConfiguration.thumbnailPath),
      MimeType: 'image/jpeg'
    },
    requestBody: {}

  });
} catch (thumbnailError) {
  console.log(thumbnailError);
}
```

Getting the following error on the above call:

```
code: 403,
errors: [
  {
    message: 'The caller does not have permission',
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'forbidden'
  }
]
```

The OAuth token is generated with the following scopes:

```
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'];
```

The Auth token is working for the following API calls and the same used to work for Thumbnail resource as well:

```
service.liveStreams.insert

service.liveBroadcasts.insert

service.liveBroadcasts.bind
```

There has been no change from our side and the same code used to work perfectly fine for last 3 to 4 months.

An insight to any change in the API endpoint or the account policy would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You may follow closely [this Google issue tracker thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175959405), since it's comprised of very much the same issue as yours.

Comment: I can confirm the same issue

Comment: Issue solved as per [Google staff report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175959405#comment9).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved by the Google team. Thanks a lot for the excellent support.